# Using Java validator for SpringBoot properties with @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

Does anybody know if it's possible to use custom ConstraintValidator for SpringBoot properties with `@Value` annotation?

Something like this:

```
@Component
@Validated
public class TestClass {
    
    @Value("${test.property}")
    @ValidValue(className=ValidValueValidator.class)
    private String testProperty;
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @David pls read this blog, you can get more idea about custom validation in spring boot 
https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/spring-boot-creating-a-custom-annotation-for-validation-edafbf9a97a4

Comment: I think, there is no interest to do it. If there is an issue with your properties, `Spring` will throw an exception anyway. Also why do you want to test your properties?

Answer (score 0):

what's your mean how to make @Validated Take effect？

- u can register a **BeanValidationPostProcessor** bean

or if your want use custom ConstraintValidator

- see Majutharan Majutharan comment